# How to fix 'class cannot extends multiple classes'

Tags: java, android

```
public class user_attandence extends HiddenCameraActivity, AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
```

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance

Comment: If `HiddenCameraActivity` already a child of `AppCompatActivity` then you should remove `AppCompatActivity` from `extends`.

Answer (score -1):

Java doesn't support it.
Use interface instead of it.